# Chain Command Blocks Not Equipping Armor?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

The following command is used to force the player to equip armor:

```
/replaceitem entity @p[type=Player] slot.armor.head chainmail_helmet 1 0 {display:{Name:"Archer Helmet",Lore:["You feel somewhat faster, and resistant to ranged damage"]},AttributeModifiers:[{AttributeName:"generic.movementSpeed",Name:"generic.movementSpeed",Amount:0.10,Operation:0,UUIDMost:24682,UUIDLeast:195471},,{AttributeName:"generic.armor",Name:"armor",Slot:"head",Amount:2.0,Operation:0,UUIDMost:100,UUIDLeast:100}],ench:[{id:0,lvl:2},{id:4,lvl:2}],Unbreakable:1}
```

And when run in a command block, it works 100% fine, but when it is part of the chain, it gives the output saying:

```
[14:09:34] Replaced slot slot.armor.head with 1 * [Archer Helmet]
```

However no changes were made to the player's GUI. Any ideas why this would happen? I'm playing Minecraft 1.10

Comment: Is the command block actually being activated? Check that the time on the output (currently 14:09:34) is changing.

Comment: Is the chain command block powered or set to always active?

Comment: Yes it is @RookieTEC9

Comment: Can you take some screenshots or better a video showcasing this?

Comment: I've always found it's better to use a comparator and impulse blocks, rather than chain blocks. Not sure what's going on with your issue though

Answer (score -1):

First make sure the chain command block is set to "always active" and in a straight line with the other leading command block. Also the chain has to start with a regular command block then the chain of chain command blocks.